# Python 3.11. Issue

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I've installed fresh version of Python 3.11. on Win 10 x64 and figured I should try Jupyter notebook, but after installing it using `pip` command (without any kind of error and previously adding python to environment variable path) I've received this error:

`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 59, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tornado.http1connection import HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado\http1connection.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tornado import iostream
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tornado.netutil import ssl_wrap_socket, _client_ssl_defaults, _server_ssl_defaults
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 35, in <module>
    _client_ssl_defaults = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 775, in create_default_context
    context.load_default_certs(purpose)
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 596, in load_default_certs
    self._load_windows_store_certs(storename, purpose)
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 588, in _load_windows_store_certs
    self.load_verify_locations(cadata=certs)
ssl.SSLError: [ASN1] nested asn1 error (_ssl.c:4004)
```

`

searching stack overflow as wheel as gitHub resulted in many dead ends.

I would be very grateful for any kind of assistance.

Comment: See this, if it helps https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4245#issuecomment-460096373

Comment: I can confirm this was the case! As described the issue was with "MUP Republike Srbije" certificate.
Many thanks to @Kris